# How to set azure storage defaultToOAuthAuthentication property

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I'm new to azure and looking to script the building of azure storage using azure cli.
I want to set defaultToOAuthAuthentication to true but cannot find any way to set this property.

Instruction on how to do it via the portal exists - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/authorize-data-operations-portal#default-to-azure-ad-authorization-in-the-azure-portal

Is it possible to set this property via a script?

Comment: Please try with “ --allow-shared-key-access”.  Setting it to false would only allow Azure AD based authorization.

Comment: I have this setting and it does not change the "Default to Azure Active Directory authorization in the Azure portal" setting that appears in configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to set this property via a script?

Thanks to `Gaurav Mantri` for suggesting the same.

I have followed this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstorageaccount?view=azps-10.0.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-9.2.0) to Storage Account with Shared Key authorization disabled.

The below Powershell cmdlet will create a new storage account with Shared Key authorization disabled and then update its configuration to use Azure AD authentication by default.

```
New-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName "<Resource-Group-Name>" -Name "<Storage-Account-Name>" -SkuName Standard_GRS -Location "EastUS" -AllowSharedKeyAccess $false
```

**Result:**

[image]

After running the above command, the storage account is created with Shared Key authorization disabled.

[image]

Comment: I have this setting and it does not change the "Default to Azure Active Directory authorization in the Azure portal" setting that appears in configuration.

Comment: Once you disable the Access keys by default it will take Azure AD Authentication.