# Azure CLI - Default to Microsoft Entra authorization in the Azure portal - how?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cli

I am trying to use the Azure CLI (bash) to create a storage account and set the "Default to Microsoft Entra authorization in the Azure portal" property to "Enabled" (as shown below):

[image]

There does not seem to be an option on the [Azure CLI storage account create command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-account-create) to do this -- or more likely, I am missing which option to include.

Can this be done via the Azure CLI?

I did try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76342199), but it had no effect (The setting was still "Disabled").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Default to Microsoft Entra authorization in the Azure portal - how?

You can use the below command to **`enable`** the Default to Microsoft Entra authorization in the Azure portal via **`Azure CLI`** commands.

**Command:**

```
az storage account update -g <Resource grp name> -n <Storage account name> --set defaultToOAuthAuthentication=true
```

**Output:**

```
PS /home/xxxx> az storage account update -g xxxx -n venkat678 --set defaultToOAuthAuthentication=true 
{
  "accessTier": "Hot",
  "accountMigrationInProgress": null,
  "allowBlobPublicAccess": true,
  "allowCrossTenantReplication": false,
  "allowSharedKeyAccess": true,
  "allowedCopyScope": null,
  "azureFilesIdentityBasedAuthentication": null,
  "blobRestoreStatus": null,
  "creationTime": "xxxx,
  "customDomain": null,
  "defaultToOAuthAuthentication": true,
  "dnsEndpointType": null,
  "enableHttpsTrafficOnly": true
```

[image]

**Portal:**

The above command executed and enabled the Default to Microsoft Entra authorization in the Azure portal.

[image]

**Reference:**

[az storage account | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-account-update)

Comment: Thanks! - I was looking for an option at the time of creation, via the "az storage account create" command.  I did look at the "az storage account update" command as well, but it is NOT very  intuitive to use the --set option as the MS docs do not include any information on WHICH options can be set.   Thanks again!